# Serializing form to JObject

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have ASP.NET Core view with two forms on a page.

```
<form id="form1">
  <input name="FirstName" />
  <input name="LastName" />
</form>
<form id="form2">
     <input name="Address1" />
     <input name="Address2" />
</form>
```

The model im trying to bind these two forms is

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public JObject ExtraFields {get;set;}
}
```

Note that `ExtraFields` is a type of JObject. Is it possible to submit these forms using jQuery so that the second form `form2` will get set to `ExtraFields`?

Comment: It is possible with custom model binders. Did you check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the serialize() method to serialize the form, then receive the value via the name property.

Sample code as below:

```
    <form asp-action="AddAddress" class="form2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address1</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="Address1" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address2</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="Address2" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

JQuery script:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 
        $(".btn-submit").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AddAddress",  //remember change the controller to your owns.
                data: $("form.form2").serialize(),  //serialize the form
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Code in the controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddAddress(string Address1, string Address2)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Besides, you could also use JQuery to extract the address, and send to the action method, like this:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {   
        $(".btn-submit").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            //using an array to store the JOject values.
            var stringArray = new Array();
            stringArray.push($("input[name='Address1']").val());
            stringArray.push($("input[name='Address2']").val());
            var postData = { extraFields: stringArray };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AddAddress",  //remember change the controller to your owns.
                data: postData, 
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                }, 
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Code in the Action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddAddress(List<string> extraFields)
    {
        return View();
    }
```